# Update class objects within threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
// Wrapper for thread call (?)
void doUpdateWrap(MyClass& obj, <args>) {
   obj.doUpdate(<args>)
}

// Make vector of class objects
std::vector<MyClass> vec;
for (int i=0; i<numObj; i++) {
  tmp = MyClass();
  vec.push_back(tmp);
}

// Update all the objects in parallel with threads
std::vector<std::thread> myThreads;
for (int i=0; i<numObj; i++) {
  myThreads.push_back(std::thread(&doUpdateWrap, vec[i], <someArgs>)
}
<join myThreads>
```

But the compiler is unhappy.  What's the right way?

Comment: Maybe because neither "<args>", nor "<someArgs>" is valid C++? And the lack of a `main()` function isn't helpful either? Can you [edit] your question and show a [mre]?

Comment: The [std::thread constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) that takes arguments to pass to its invocable as arguments requires those arguments to be copyable. You can't make a copy of a `MyClass&` reference, so you have to change `doUpdateWrap` to something that can accept its arguments by value. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/qcqqP9zd5) I've used [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) but you could also pass `MyClass*` pointers.

Comment: It seems to work with the same doUpdateWrap if I call it with std::ref(vec[i]).